# Under which condition is f(X) $F_t$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X_t$ be $F_t$ measurable for a filtration $F_t$, under which condition of function $f$ can we say that $f(X_t)$ is also $F_t$ measurable? Is measurability of $f$ enough?

Thanks in advance for any information

Comment: Yes of course .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you want $f$ to be Borel measurable, i.e. such that $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel set whenever $B$ is.

It's not clear if that's what you mean by "measurable". In particular, it is typically not good enough to just require that $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is *Lebesgue* measurable, i.e. that $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Lebesgue measurable set whenever $B$ is Borel.

See also [Why do probabilists take random variables to be Borel (and not Lebesgue) measurable?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31603/why-do-probabilists-take-random-variables-to-be-borel-and-not-lebesgue-measura)